# Why doesn't javascript function work in html reference?

Tags: javascript, html

```
function ClearAll() {
    localStorage.clear();
    doShowAll();
}
```

```
<?php
    session_start();
    header('Location: index.html');
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>shopping cart</title>
        <script src="Storage.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="StorageStyle.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>ClearAll();</script>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
    $_SESSION['loggued_on_user'] = NULL;
?>
```

I want to log out and to execute function `ClearAll` from js file at the same time. However I have obtained logout without cleaning the content in js.

Comment: What does `header('Location: index.html');` do?

Comment: it is just login page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> header('Location: index.html');
> ```

When you issue an HTTP redirect, most clients (including ALL mainstream browsers) will follow it *transparently*.

The body of the HTTP response (which is your HTML document with the JavaScript in it) is only used by clients which **don't** follow the redirect automatically.

Since the HTML document isn't rendered, the JavaScript isn't executed.

---

You should probably run the JS with a `click` event handler that listens on the button that the user clicked on the previous page to initiate the logging out.